# direct acces image url

Tags: 7, media, uri

I searched but cannot find an answer to my question.

I'm using Drupal 7 and created content with image. The path of the content is `http://example.com/page/content`

My problem: I want to share the URL of the image to facebook.

`http://example.com/sites/default/files/image01.jpg`

But the request URL shows "404 not found".

I have set the media to show in public.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I tried to enhance the grammar / spelling of your question. But only those things I'm sure you wanted to ask (to ensure I didn't change the meaning of your question). However I'm not 100% sure who or what 'fb' is (only 99%, but don't want to do any guessing ...). Please EDIT your question to make that clear. While you do so, please also better explain the "I want to share the URL of the image to fb." part of your question (again: I "think" I understand what you mean, but don't want to guess what the question really is ... Good luck!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens fb should be facebook

Comment: Merci @AdrianCidAlmaguer, ... "I" leave it to somebody else to potentially change the meaning of the question. Better still: it would be nice if the OPer would clarify that with the extra EDIT I recommended, no? Not sure if it applies for "fb", but there are quite a few other 2-letter abbreviations with multiple meanings. AA, BB, CC, BA, FF, TB ... to just name a few. PS (oeps, another one ...): maybe FB stands for FireBird?

Answer (score 0):

If that file does actually exist within /sites/default/files/ then your link should work.

Have you messed around with the .htaccess file in the root of your site? Or it could be the hosting package your on as there's a rule in that htaccess to not go into drupal if the file exists in that directory

Comment: thanks, i have found the problem, the problem is hotlinking in .htaccess RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC] , i removed it and fix the problem